# Write to File Issues - 'list' object is not callable (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

The following script is only a 10% sample of a much larger calculator which part of an assignment.
The only real issue I have run into is when it comes to `'list' object is not callable` - everything else is actually working perfectly.
I have researched this and applied various examples and each one then opens a new issue and it doesn't end. So, I figured I would share it here to see where I am failing here.

```
"""
Example of the string calculator issues (Lists)
"""

# Import datetime
from datetime import datetime

# Establish Timestamp Object
ts = datetime.now()
timestamp = ts.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")

# File
Ofile = open("testfile.txt", "w")
# Write to File Test - Timestamp
Ofile.write("\n     Start Timestamp = "+str(timestamp))

# Simple Add Calculator
num1 = float(input("\nPlease select your first number to Add: "))
num2 = float(input("\nPlease select your second number to Add: "))
add1 = float(num1+num2)
print(f"\nAdding, {num1} + {num2} =",add1)
key = input("\nPress any key to continue.")
Ofile.write("\n     Timestamp: "+str(timestamp))
Ofile.write("\n     The result of Adding "+str(num1)+" and "+str(num2)+" is: "+str(add1))
Ofile.close()
Ofile = open("testfile.txt", "r")
print(Ofile.read())
key = input("\nPress any key to continue.")

Ofile = open("testfile.txt", "a")

# String Calculator
print("/nPlease enter two numbers to calculate, each separated n\by a space or comma and then provide the arithmetic symbol ( + )")
print('''

     Example:  
        45 45 +
        578,945,+
''')
scalc = input("\nInput: ")
if scalc.find(" ") != -1:
    str = scalc.split(" ")
elif scalc.find(",") != -1:
    str = scalc.split(",")
else:
    print("\nThat was an invalid Entry. Please try again.")
num3 = float(str[0]) 
num4 = float(str[1]) 
if str[2] == "+": 
    add2 = float(num3+num4)
print(f"\nAdding, {num3} + {num4} =",add2)
key = input("\nPress any key to continue.")
# Issues with writing to file   
Ofile.write("\n     Timestamp: "+str(timestamp)) # Issue: ('list' object is not callable)
Ofile.write("\n     The result of Adding "+str(num3)+" and "+str(num4)+" is: "+str(add2)) # Issue: ('list' object is not callable)
Ofile.close()
Ofile = open("testfile.txt", "r")
print(Ofile.read())
key = input("\nPress any key to continue.")
```

Comment: You assigned a list to the name `str`, then you tried to call the built-in function `str`. Use a different name for your list.

Comment: I would also suggest that you use the 'with' statement for contextually handling your ressources.

Comment: @maciejwww - Thank you is something that should be edited out? Really? And the list tag you added is for HTML - not Python. I was going to add it and it's not the correct tag.

Comment: @furthark [Yes, "thank you" should be edited out of questions.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950)

Comment: I think you mean salutations? [Should 'Hi', 'thanks', taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)

Comment: @khelwood Very well thank you for letting me know. I am not sure why gratitude is not included, but I will not add it in the future.

Comment: @maciejwww Noted. Won't happen again. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't assign or use the predefined classes/functions/keywords as variables.

Use the modified code below:

```
"""
Example of the string calculator issues (Lists)
"""

# Import datetime
from datetime import datetime

# Establish Timestamp Object
ts = datetime.now()
timestamp = ts.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")

# File
Ofile = open("testfile.txt", "w")
# Write to File Test - Timestamp
Ofile.write("\n     Start Timestamp = "+str(timestamp))

# Simple Add Calculator
num1 = float(input("\nPlease select your first number to Add: "))
num2 = float(input("\nPlease select your second number to Add: "))
add1 = float(num1+num2)
print(f"\nAdding, {num1} + {num2} =",add1)
key = input("\nPress any key to continue.")
Ofile.write("\n     Timestamp: "+str(timestamp))
Ofile.write("\n     The result of Adding "+str(num1)+" and "+str(num2)+" is: "+str(add1))
Ofile.close()
Ofile = open("testfile.txt", "r")
print(Ofile.read())
key = input("\nPress any key to continue.")

Ofile = open("testfile.txt", "a")

# String Calculator
print("/nPlease enter two numbers to calculate, each separated n\by a space or comma and then provide the arithmetic symbol ( + )")
print('''

     Example:  
        45 45 +
        578,945,+
''')
scalc = input("\nInput: ")
if scalc.find(" ") != -1:
    st = scalc.split(" ")
elif scalc.find(",") != -1:
    st = scalc.split(",")
else:
    print("\nThat was an invalid Entry. Please try again.")
num3 = float(st[0]) 
num4 = float(st[1]) 
if st[2] == "+": 
    add2 = float(num3+num4)
print(f"\nAdding, {num3} + {num4} =",add2)
key = input("\nPress any key to continue.")
# Issues with writing to file   
Ofile.write("\n     Timestamp: "+str(timestamp)) # Issue: ('list' object is not callable)
Ofile.write("\n     The result of Adding "+str(num3)+" and "+str(num4)+" is: "+str(add2)) # Issue: ('list' object is not callable)
Ofile.close()
Ofile = open("testfile.txt", "r")
print(Ofile.read())
key = input("\nPress any key to continue.")
```

Comment: Thank you sir, yes that fixed the issue. I am looking at what I actually did wrong. So basically the issue was with the 'str'?

Comment: In python, modifying the predefined methods (it's bad though) is possible I.e., str, list, tuple, etc., That's what you did, after that you'll not be able to use that function. (str)